# Datetime conversion error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My table contains the column 'StartDate' and value stored in the column is in format '23.1.2018'.

I am writing a select query where I am passing FromDate and ToDate.

```
@FromDate = '2018-08-01'
@ToDate = '2018-08-05'
```

After execution, I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Apart from that I have used several techniques of CAST and CONVERT like `CONVERT(date, StartDate, 104)` and so on...

But the same error persists.

Looking forward to solution.

```
select * 
from [dbo].[LMT2_ServerLicenseUser] 
where cast(cast(startdate as datetime(7)) as date) = cast(cast(@FromDate as datetime(7)) as date)

SELECT CONVERT(date, '2018-08-01')

select convert(varchar, '24.11.2017', 23)   

select CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT(CONVERT(date, StartDate, 104), RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime), 8)), 103)
```

Comment: The format `yyyy-MM-dd` is an ambiguous format, SQL Server will most likely interpret it as `yyyy-dd-MM`. The only unambiguous formats in SQL Server are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssssss`. I also note that you `CAST` to the datatype `datetime(7)` in your SQL. `datetime` doesn't have a scale/precision value; `datetime2` however does. SQL Server 2005 doesn't support `datetime2` though. What *are* you using here?

Comment: Please [don't use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 1):

It is the language setting of the login that controls how these ambiguous date formats are interpreted (though this can be overridden with an explicit SET DATEFORMAT statement).

The DEFAULT_LANGUAGE can be changed via ALTER LOGIN

try using 103

SELECT  CONVERT(date, '25/08/2008',103)

Answer (score 0):

First i would suggest to change you date style not immediate effect but later you need to do, otherwise you have to pay such to do conversations (`varchar` -> `date`)

For your current date format you can use `convert()` function with style code of `103`

```
select sl.* 
from [dbo].[LMT2_ServerLicenseUser] sl
where convert(date, startdate, 103) >= @fromdate and
      convert(date, startdate, 103) <= @todate;
```

Comment: I changed it to below

Declare FromDate varchar(50)
Set FromDate = '2018-08-01'
select * from [dbo].[LMT2_ServerLicenseUser] where convert(date, startdate, 103) = convert(date, FromDate, 103)

Error:Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: If your data really contains smth like '23.1.2018', it cannot be converted to date because it's not of a definite format, it should be first converted to '23.**01**.2018', and the same for a day, if you have '1.1.2018' it should be transformed into '01.10.2018' before trying to convert to a date